# Why does pow output 0 even when using %f?

Tags: c, pow

I am completely new to c, so I was trying to use the pow function as I'm following a tutorial. On the tutorial (and I followed the code exactly as they wrote it), their output is correct, but all I get is 0.000000. Does anyone know why this happened?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    printf("%f", pow(4, 3));



    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
0.000000
```

Comment: I get `64.000000` for output. But I also get a warning about `pow()` having an implicit declaration.

Comment: Try including `<math.h>` and enable all warnings to save time.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Insert `#include <math.h>`, turn on warnings in your compiler, pay attention to warning messages, and promote warnings to errors.

Without `<math.h>`, `pow` is not declared, and `pow(4, 3)` passes arguments as `int`. `pow` needs its arguments passed as `double`, the behavior when they are passed as `int` is not defined by the C standard. Further, the return type of `pow` will be assumed to be `int`, but the actual return type is `double`, and the behavior of the function call with this mismatch is also not defined. And passing an `int` value for a `printf` conversion of `%f` also has behavior not defined by the C standard.

Comment: What is the problem of passing `int` as input in `pow`, isn't it a simple promotion rule?

Comment: @MatheusRossiSaciotto: If a function is declared with a prototype (parameter declarations), arguments will be converted to the types of the parameters. When a function is not declared (or has `...` for variable arguments), the default argument promotions are used. These perform the integer promotions and promote `float` to `double`, but they do not promote `int` to `double`. So `pow(4, 3)` with no declaration of `pow` passes `int` arguments without any conversion.

Comment: You are right, for some reason `gcc` promotes despite of the implicit declaration, but `MSVC` doesn't.

Comment: @MatheusRossiSaciotto: GCC likely has some built-in knowledge of `pow`. Because it is reserved for use as an external identifier, using it (as an external identifier) for anything other than the standard library `pow` has undefined behavior, so the compiler is not bound by the normal rules for undeclared or unprototyped functions—it can implement whatever behavior it pleases.

Answer (score 1):

If you work in linux and you want to insert `#include <math.h>` don't forget to compile with `-lm` to link the math  library.

And by the way if you want to use float numbers try to use `powf`.

Syntax: `float powf(float___x,float___y);`.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This is a useful answer, but it would be easier to read with complete sentences, punctuation, and `\`` characters around the code (so that it comes out as `-lm` instead of -lm).  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for more tips on formatting.

Comment: You're welcome!  There's an "Edit" button if you'd like to make changes to your answer.